# Qt: No metadata by meta.enumeratorCount() for enum in Q_OBJECT, why?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qobject

I have the following class, where I try to obtain some metadata of an `enum MyEnum`. However, when looping over `meta.enumeratorCount()` its count is always 0. Basically I was follwing [this example here](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/10/09/coding-tip-pretty-printing-enum-values/). In order to find the problem, I was trying the same with methods too, same problem - method count 0. Code compiles, no errors no warnings.

Must be a silly mistake .... maybe you can help me

```
class FsxSimConnectQtfier : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FsxSimConnectQtfier(QObject *parent = 0);
    enum MyEnum { G1, G2 };
    static const QString simConnectExceptionToString(const DWORD id);
};

const QString FsxSimConnectQtfier::simConnectExceptionToString(const DWORD id) {
    // int i= FsxSimConnectQtfier::staticMetaObject.indexOfEnumerator("MyEnum");
    // -1 -> not found, why?
    QMetaObject meta = FsxSimConnectQtfier::staticMetaObject;
    for (int i=0; i < meta.enumeratorCount(); ++i) {
        QMetaEnum m = meta.enumerator(i); // never reached, why?
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the enum with the metadata system using [the `Q_ENUMS()` macro](http://qt-project.org/doc/qobject.html#Q_ENUMS):

```
class FsxSimConnectQtfier : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(MyEnum)  // <--- 

public:
    explicit FsxSimConnectQtfier(QObject *parent = 0);
    enum MyEnum { G1, G2 };
    static const QString simConnectExceptionToString(const unsigned int id);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, if you have any idea about the follow up, maybe you can help me out again. If not, never mind.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690684/qt-fy-existing-enum-to-use-with-qt-metadata