# Qt-fy existing enum to use with Qt metadata

Tags: enums, qt4, qobject

Let's assume I have an existing `enum X { A, B }` and want to use it with Qt metadata such as `QMetaObject` / `QMetaEnum`.

```
QMetaObject meta = FsxSimConnectQtfier::staticMetaObject;
for (int i=0; i < meta.enumeratorCount(); ++i) {
    QMetaEnum m = meta.enumerator(i);
}
```

If I define my `enum` within a `Q_OBJECT` class, all is fine, i.e. I can retrieve `MyEnum` [by the metadata system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679057/qt-no-metadata-by-meta-enumeratorcount-for-enum-in-q-object-why). But how can I make `X` available for the metadata system?

```
class FsxSimConnectQtfier : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(MyEnum) 
    Q_ENUMS(X) // not working
public:
    explicit FsxSimConnectQtfier(QObject *parent = 0);
    enum MyEnum { G1, G2 };
    // how can I make enum X available for the metadata system
    // I have tried typedef, but did not work
    static const QString simConnectExceptionToString(const unsigned int id);
};
```

1. This is a follow up of: [Qt: No metadata by meta.enumeratorCount() for enum in Q_OBJECT, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679057/qt-no-metadata-by-meta-enumeratorcount-for-enum-in-q-object-why)
2. Motivation: The real `enum X` contains many exception codes, and I want to use the metadata system to fetch the original descriptive text, pretty much as [here](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/10/09/coding-tip-pretty-printing-enum-values/). The original `enum` is not(!) an `Q_OBJECT`.