# Unable to iterate over a Qt enumeration

Tags: c++, qt, enumeration, qgadget

I am trying to iterate over an enumeration.

```
    class MyEnumClass : public QObject
    {
        Q_GADGET
        Q_ENUMS(MyEnum)

    public:
        enum MyEnum
        {
            a, b, c
        };

        MyEnumClass(QObject *parent = 0){}
    };

    void listAllItems()
    {    
        QMetaObject meta = MyEnumClass::staticMetaObject;
        int count =  meta.enumeratorCount();
        for (int i=0; i < count; ++i)
        {
           QMetaEnum m = meta.enumerator(i);
           QString x;
           MyEnumClass::MyEnum y;
           x = m.valueToKey(i);
           y = (MyEnumClass::MyEnum)m.value(i);
        }
    }
```

As I step through the loop I should be able to see my enumeration, with name in x and value in y.

Unfortunately I am able to only see the first value, count is always 1.

I looked at this question to figure out the code above - but I did reqister my enum, my problem should be a different one.
[Qt: No metadata by meta.enumeratorCount() for enum in Q_OBJECT, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679057/qt-no-metadata-by-meta-enumeratorcount-for-enum-in-q-object-why)

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like `meta.enumeratorCount()` will return the number of registered enums. In your case, you have only one. You want to get the [`QMetaEnum`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaenum.html) corresponding to `MyEnum` by calling `meta.enumerator(0)`. You can then use `QMetaEnum::keyCount` and `QMetaEnum::key` to list the keys in the enum.